# The position of draggable image is wrong by jQuery sortable

Tags: php, html, css, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a form to change order of images in db. Here is the code:

**index.css**

```
#gallery {
  width: 1057px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#image-list {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#image-list li {
  margin: 10px 20px 10px 0px;
  display: inline-block;
}

#image-list li img {
  width: 300px;
}

#image-container {
  margin-bottom: 14px;
}
```

**index.php**

```
<form id="image-container" action="" method="post">
    <ul id="image-list">
    <?php foreach ($final_array as $image): ?>
        <?php echo '<li id="image_' . $image['id'] . '">
            <input id="' . $image['name'] . '" name="deletebox[]" value="' . $image['name'] . '" type="checkbox"> 
            <label for="' . $image['name'] . '"> 
               <img src="' . $targetDir . $image['name'] . '"/>
            </label>
        </li>' ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
   </ul>
```

this is jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    let dropIndex;
    $("#image-list").sortable({
        update: function (event, ui) {
            dropIndex = ui.item.index();
        }
    });
    $('#submit').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        let imageIdsArray = [];
        $('#image-list li').each(function () {
          let id = $(this).attr('id');
          let split_id = id.split("_");
          imageIdsArray.push(split_id[1]);
        });
    $.ajax({......
```

the problem is - when page is not scrolled, the draggable image position relative to the mouse cursor is right.

[image]

But if a user scrolls the page down (there could be tens of rows of images), the position of draggable image is wrong, in fact it appears 100-200px higher than it should be:

[image]

I can't find the way how to debug it. Where to start looking?

Comment: UP. 
Is it really unknown behaviour and I am the first who discovered it ?